# admin state Vs link state from a network engineer stand point

Tags: switch, interface

On a network switch, if the admin state is made "UP" by using a "no shutdown" on that physical interface then it remains "UP" what so ever until the port is configured as "shutdown". This is the current behavior on OpenSwitch NOS. Is this correct behavior? I'd like this behavior to be as close to what network engineers would expect.

This behavior has been changed recently (last month). Earlier the behavior was that if the plug-gable module on that interface was disconnected then the admin state would say "DOWN". Need to figure this out from a network engineer or current practices  stand point. I'm new to networking. Currently contributing to OpenSwitch project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cisco land, admin down is only seen when an engineer (aka admin) :) issues the "shutdown" command on the interface.

As per [this thread,](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16625/what-can-cause-fastethernet-is-up-line-protocol-is-down-on-cisco-switch) other statuses include down/down and up/down. If there is no cable connected to the port the interface is down/down. If there is a cable connected but there's an issue, the interface will be up/down.